# Insert persian characters in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, special-characters, sqldatatypes

I am trying to insert `Ḩāfiz̧ Moghul` into a SQL database column with `nvarchar(100)` set as the datatype.

For some reason it is replacing the first letter with a `?`

How do I fix this?

Comment: I am attempting to perform an update query directly within SQL Management Studio. It seems that every character with that small character under a letter (i.e. Ḩ) is being replaced with the ?

Comment: I am using the SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_Cl_AS. This database contains primarily English characters but I would like it to be universal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to insert Unicode characters as string literals in a SQL statement, you **must** prefix the string with a `N` character:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(UnicodeColum)
VALUES (N'Ḩāfiz̧ Moghul');
```

If you *omit* the `N` prefix, the string will be converted to **non-Unicode** `Varchar` before being inserted.